# Для чего toString() в StringBuffer?

Tags: java, строки, сравнение, печать

Чем отличаются эти строчки ?

Зачем `toString()` ?

Тут я беру число из массива и сравниваю с обратным (проверяю на полиндром)

Но если убрать `toString()` в конце условия, то не сработает ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (Integer.toString(arr[i]).equals(new StringBuffer().append(Integer.toString(arr[i])).reverse().toString()))
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Но вот другой пример без `toString()` работает:

```
System.out.print(new StringBuffer().append("Hello").reverse());
```

> `elloH`

Comment: *Зачем toString() ?* Чтобы получить строку. *Но вот другой пример без toString() работает:* Потому что `System.out.print` делает `toString()` за Вас.

Comment: equals принимает Object, а в самой реализации есть такая конструкция `if (anObject instanceof String) { ... } else return false;`, тк приходит StringBuilder, то поэтому и условие false. Можно использовать contentEquals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `System.out.print()` вызывает `toString()` автоматически. Так что приведение типов делать не требуется. А вот метод `equals()` требует параметр того же типа что и сам объект. Если переопределить этот метод, то конструкция в выражении будет работать. Для более детального понимания как работает метод `print()` надо смотреть документацию.